# Get list of duplicate map keys from multiple maps

Tags: java, java-stream

I have multiple maps of arrays.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, List<String>> map3 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, List<String>> map4 = new HashMap<>();
```

I want to get the list of duplicate map keys from the multiple maps.

For example

```
map1.put("k0", Arrays.asList("a0", "a1"));
map1.put("k1", Arrays.asList("b0", "b1"));

map2.put("k1", Arrays.asList("z1", "z2"));
map2.put("k2", Arrays.asList("z1", "z2"));

map3.put("k1", Arrays.asList("z1", "z2"));
map3.put("k3", Arrays.asList("z1", "z2"));

map4.put("k3", Arrays.asList("z1", "z2"));
map4.put("k4", Arrays.asList("z1", "z2"));

map5.put("k0", Arrays.asList("z1", "z2"));
map5.put("k5", Arrays.asList("z1", "z2"));

// Expected output is 
List: [k0, k1, k3]
```

Aside from iterating through all of the map keys, checking if a set contains the key, and if not adding the key to the set, I can't think of any cleaner ways of doing this. Is there a way to accomplish this with streams?

Comment: you don't need to check if Set contains the key as Set items are unique. Just iterate throw the all keys, add them to the set and use the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@SafeVarargs
private static Set<String> findDuplicateKeys(Map<String, ?>... maps) {
    Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
    return Arrays.stream(maps)
            .flatMap(map -> map.keySet().stream())
            .filter(key -> !keys.add(key))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

I would model the result as a set rather than list, since no duplicate elements are possible.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using java-stream tag, you can solve your problem like so:

```
Set<String> duplicateKeys = Stream.of(map1.keySet(), map2.keySet(), map3.keySet(), map4.keySet(), map5.keySet())
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), x -> false, (a, b) -> true))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Output

```
[k0, k1, k3]
```

---

`.collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), x -> false, (a, b) -> true))` this return a `Map<String, Boolean>` it return the key and `true` if duplicate and `false` if not, then you just filter to get only the entries where the value is true `.filter(Map.Entry::getValue)` which represent the duplicate ones.

Comment: Wow, thank you. Can you explain a little bit how this works, especially the "Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), x -> false, (a, b) -> true)"?

Comment: @villabilla Yes It is a trick to collect as a Map and in the value part you just use a true for duplicate and false for not duplicate

Comment: Can you please explain how the following part works (technically) Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), x -> false, (a, b) -> true)

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos the `x -> false` mean if there are a unique element then return false, the `(a, b) -> true` mean if a and b are equals this mean there are duplicate so return true, for more details [read this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-)

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can try this. Create the stream of maps, then `flatMap` it to a stream of keys, then collect the keys into a `Map` counting how many of each key there is, then stream that EntrySet, `Set<Map.Entry>`, filter by the count of the occurrence of the keys, map that to the key values and collect to a list. This should be able to run with `.parallel()`.

```
 private List<String> findDups(Map<String, ?>... maps) {
 return Arrays.asList(maps).stream()
  .flatMap(m->m.keySet().stream())
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
  .entrySet().stream()
  .filter(es->es.getValue() > 1)
  .map(es->es.getKey())
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```